# Why do I have poor performance with Alienware m17x r1 and dual GTX260m?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, steam

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with the Nvidia drivers (310.14), my performance in both Team Fortress 2 and Counter Strike Source is sporadic. In some instances, I manage to get between 150 and 250 fps and other times, I can barely break 20fps.

Machine spec is as follows:

- Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q9000 @ 2.00GHz × 4
- 8GB RAM
- Onboard Nvidia 9400 (which i disabled in the BIOS)
- Dual GTX260m connected in SLI

Here is the tail end of my xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "SLI" "On"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I am also having problems with HDMI output (video and sound) working with my TV.

Another note: Changing any of the video settings in either game has no effect on the framerate at all.

Comment: Not sure if this might help anyone but so far I've turned off SLI and that has seemed to give me a huge performance boost in game (both in CSS and Team Fortress 2). It also seems like a more stable framerate now (about 100fps average in game compared to the 15fps i used to get sometimes). Also, with SLI set to off (nvidia-xconfig --sli=off), i now have my HDMI output back (although in twin view and clone mode, my res on my TV is a little out but it is perfect for watching movies etc).